# Classpath for custom Solr Transformer

Tags: solr, classpath, jetty

I have written a custom Transformer subclass for the Solr DataImportHandler.   It is in a jar file, but I can't figure out how to get solr to find it.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/Transformer
```

I've configured the data-config.xml file with the full path to the custom transformer:

```
transformer="RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer,com.mycompany.xform.MyTransformer"
```

I've tried my jar file in every /lib, /dist directory I could find, leading me to believe that it is a problem with a dependent file. It would be very nice if the logs indicated the actual class that can't be found, but they are pretty unhelpful. 
If I remove the MyTransformer specification, the dataimporthandler works just fine.

Comment: It looks like your webapp cannot find the base class (org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.Transformer) of your own class.

Comment: Yes, that is obviously the problem.  But how do I fix it?

Comment: Is this problem ever resolved? If so how is it resolved? I am starting solr using start,jar from the example directory

Comment: Few minutes after my earlier post - the class not found  error is solved by dropping the custome transformer jar in the <core name>/lib/* directory. I am using with the jetty start.jar mode

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that it has to do with your class loader. (assuming you are using Tomcat: https://sec1.woopra.com/docs/class-loader-howto.html)

If you put your jar into "Common" Classloader directory, then all it's dependencies need to also be available to that classloader. So presumably your Solr classes are in the webapps directory (ie WEB-INF/lib), so how is tomcat supposed to know where to find the right class. For instance, consider you have two versions of the Solr in different webapp directories? which version should Tomcat use?

So i think you solution is to put your jar into the Solr webapp.

Comment: what if solr is started using jetty start,jar ?

Comment: Few minutes after my earlier post - the class not found  error is solved by dropping the custome transformer jar in the <core name>/lib/* directory. I am using with the jetty start.jar mode

Answer (score 0):

I put my custom transformer jar file into solr/lib; the same directory as the jetty.jar file.

I also had to put build and put apache-solr-dataimporthandler-1.4.1-dev.jar in the same solr/lib directory.

Comment: You mean you have rebuild apache-solr-dataimporthandler-1.4.1-dev.jar  ?  Why and what is included in the new build?

Comment: Few minutes after my earlier post - the class not found  error is solved by dropping the custome transformer jar in the <core name>/lib/* directory. I am using with the jetty start.jar mode